# Ruby - Call method from a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method to set the locale on currencies.

```
def local_number_to_currency(u)
      number_to_currency u,
        separator: ".",
        delimiter: ",",
        precision: 0,
        locale: :fr,
        raise: true  
    end
```

I would like to make `:fr` a variable in order to set it according to a variable based on a attribute called Deal's modal 'Country' attribute

```
def extract_locale_from_country(country)       
    COUNTRY_TO_YML_LOCALE_CODE[country] || DefaultLocale
  end

def local_number_to_currency(u)
      number_to_currency u,
        separator: ".",
        delimiter: ",",
        precision: 0,
        locale: :#{extract_locale_from_country(deal.country)},
        raise: true  
    end
```

Of course the line `locale: :#{extract_locale_from_country(deal.country)}` does not work. I don't know how to replace `:fr` by `:{call amethod here}` in ruby

How to achieve that?

Comment: `#{...}` only works in string literals, use `locale: extract_locale_from_country(...)` instead.

Comment: _Sidenote_: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should explicitly convert String to Symbol

```
extract_locale_from_country(deal.country).to_sym
```

Comment: @Mathieu in this case you could also just wrap your `#{ }` in quotes like `:"#{extract_locale_from_country(deal.country)}",` which accomplishes the same thing, but takes advantage of the fact that `:foo == :"foo"`

Comment: @maxpleaner The fact that `:foo == :"foo"` allows to _skip using string extrapolation_ for these two particular cases. What you meant is probably “takes advantage of the fact that `:foo != "foo"`, but `"#{:foo}" == "#{'foo'}"`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I was saying the original code would work if quotations were simply added.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings into symbols directly with `to_sym`-methode.

```
...
locale: :extract_locale_from_country(deal.country).to_sym,
...
```

But you should be careful to convert user input into symbols, because "older" ruby versions (<2.2) don't gc symbols.

[Symbol GC in Ruby 2.2](http://www.sitepoint.com/symbol-gc-ruby-2-2/)